# Can I include uncovered assemblies in the DotCover statistics in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0, dotcover

I have a TeamCity 7.0 project that covers a solution with a number of output assemblies.  The only assemblies that appear in the DotCover statistics are the ones that have at least one line of code covered by tests.  Is it possible to also include the assemblies completely uncovered by tests in the statistics?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. 
Here is a corresponding request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-2305 .
You are welcome to track its status.